# Emacs return to indented code line when press 'return' key

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs 22.2.1 and Ubuntu 9.04

I have done this in my .emacs file. Which indents and creates a new line each time I press ';' or '{ }'

```
if(success == 0)
{
    printf("Success\n");
    <---- if I press return key here it will go
<-- to here, and I have to tab to go to the code line.
```

However, if I press the return key it will take me to column 0 not the indent line of code I am working on i.e.

```
(require 'cc-mode)

;; Auto indent on insertion of a curly brace
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook '(lambda()
 (c-toggle-auto-state t)))

;; Set coding style to indent 4 spaces
(setq c-default-style "bsd"
  c-basic-offset 4)
```

Comment: Do you really want ';' to create a newline? what does that do to for loops? If you do, then I'd suggest creating a new function that self-inserts the ; and then does the newline-and-indent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (define-key c-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)))
```

maps return to newline + indent. Or, if you like, you can form the habit of typing C-j instead of return, since C-j is already mapped to this function.

Comment: Better yet, add this onto the `prog-mode-hook`

Answer (score 2):

The way to find that out is

- know that C-j does what you want
- use C-h k C-j to find out that C-j is mapped to `newline-and-indent`
- look up remapping keys in the EMACS Info.

Comment: "The way to find out is [...] know [something]."